# My bird controller is not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game on the Unity Game Engine where you control a bird. When I attached my script to the bird and clicked play, the bird wouldn't turn. The bird was able to rotate but not actually turn left and right. My up and down movement is also very robotic-like and I was wondering if there is a way to improve it. I am very new to Unity and coding and some help would be greatly appreciated.

My code that I used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BirdController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float FlySpeed = 5;
    public float YawAmount = 1;
    public float PitchAmount = 1;

    private float Yaw;
    private float Pitch;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //move forward
        transform.position += transform.forward * FlySpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        //inputs
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //yaw, pitch, roll
        Yaw += horizontalInput * YawAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        Pitch += verticalInput * PitchAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        float pitch = Mathf.Lerp(0, 50, Mathf.Abs(verticalInput)) * Mathf.Sign(verticalInput);
        float roll = Mathf.Lerp(0, 70, Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput)) * -Mathf.Sign(horizontalInput);

        //apply rotation.
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * Yaw + Vector3.right * pitch + Vector3.forward * roll);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * Pitch + Vector3.left * pitch + Vector3.forward * roll);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "Robotic like" you mean that the bird always moves up and down at the same speed, try adding x, y, and z velocity variables to the `BirdController` Class. When the arrow keys are pressed, you can change that velocity, and then constantly change the position of the object by the velocity variables in each axis.

Change this:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * FlySpeed * Time.deltaTime;

float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

to this:

```
transform.position += new Vector3(xVelocity, yVelocity, zVelocity) * FlySpeed * Time.deltaTime;

xVelocity += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
yVelocity += Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
zVelocity = 0;

xVelocity /=2;
yVelocity /=2
```

I haven't yet tested this code, so it may not work as expected.

Comment: Just tested I, and with a little tweaking and adding I got it to work, thank you so much!